# Count number of times values increase in range - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, range

how are you? I'm just not sure what to do here, but I surely can use your help!

I have a series of values in a row range, such as in the following:

`1000 2000 1500 2100 3200`

I need to figure out a google sheets formula to put in the 6th cell of this row that counts the number of times the value of any cell is greater than the one to the left of it. In this example, my result should be `3`.

Is there any way that this can be done? In Excel or Google Sheets, either is great to learn.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try the following formula

```
=COUNTIF(QUERY({{"";TRANSPOSE(B2:F2)},{TRANSPOSE(B2:F2);""}}, 
               "select Col1-Col2 offset 1 label Col1-Col2 ''",0), "<0")
```

[image]

Comment: This works absolutely perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: Hey @marikamitsos, can you by any chance tell me how to calculate the reverse? That is, to count how many times the values decrease over the range, starting from left to right?

Comment: Hey @CrystalThomas. Sorry for the late reply. *"to count how many times the values decrease over the range, starting from left to right"* just change `<0` to `>0`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have data in A2:E, place the following in F2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(IF(B2:E>A2:D,1,0),SEQUENCE(4,1,1,0))))`

Since there are only four columns that might be greater than others (B:E), you can structure it this way. `MMULT` is hard to explain, but it essentially multiplies everything in each row of one matrix (range) by everything in another range and then adds them. `SEQUENCE` just forms a column of four 1's by which to multiply then add together everything in each row of the first range. Since anything times 1 is the original number, this just serves to to row-by-row addition.

This formula will process as many rows as have data in A2:E.

Comment: @Crystal, I see that you've asked elsewhere on page if formulas will work rows where data fills "different lengths." Mine will with simple modifications. But it would be most efficient to show you on a a sample spreadsheet. As others have requested, please share a link to such a sheet, being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone > Editor." In it, include, say, 10 rows of data in the same range as that data appears in your actual sheet and of varying lengths that reflect that of your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

try in 7th column on row 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IF(A2:E4<B2:F4, 1, 0), {1;1;1;1;1}^0))
```

[image]

Comment: yes, my thought as well. However, you don't need that extra column, since the only columns that might be greater are B:E. (See my newly added reply.)

Comment: It doesn't fail if starting in A; it was designed to start in A. And I only process through E, not F. Look again (or better yet, pop my solution into a sheet with numbers in A2:E. My formula is comparing B2:E with A2:D, so A2:E are compared.

Comment: @ErikTyler yes, indeed thats true

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone, I really appreciate your feedback. Here is the challenge: not every row is the same length. Though I've found another solution above, it's still good to learn - will this work still?

Comment: @CrystalThomas can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Hello everyone! Thank you so much for the replies, and sorry for the late return. I'm so grateful for all of your responses. I have the sheet still, but the problem is solved. Will you still need it?